# How to use PowerShell to scrape specific Bet365 tag

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

I am interested in using PowerShell to pull from the Bet365 website, to recursively pull data from different in-play football matches, however I cannot seem to see the class I want to pull from.
ml1-SoccerStatsBar_MiniBarValue-1...when I inspect the page.

https://www.bet365.com/#/IP/

Comment: It looks like you got distracted while writing this question, did someone score a goal? Could you provide your PowerShell code please

Comment: thanks for the reply, just this at the moment $url ="https://www.bet365.com/#/IP/"

$r=Invoke-WebRequest $url


$r.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('div') |
  Where-Object { $_.className -eq 'ml1-SoccerStatsBar_MiniBarValue ml1-SoccerStatsBar_MiniBarValue-1 ' }